# JSP get session name and Id, ApplicationData class is not exist

Tags: java, jsp, session, session-cookies, session-state

I want to get the names and IDs of working sessions in my server with is an apache tomcat 7.

I tried this: (after googling )

```
// Get my custom application-scoped attribute
    ApplicationData applicationData = getApplicationData();
    // Get the set of all SessionData objects and add myself to it
    Set<SessionData> activeSessions = applicationData.getActiveSessions();
    if (!activeSessions.contains(this)) {
        activeSessions.add(this);
    }
```

but it seems that `ApplicationData` is not an existed class.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use jsp page or servlet and use this java code :

```
String id=session.getId();
Date Creation_Time=new Date(session.getCreationTime());
Data Last_Access_time=new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());
```

to see the  date in full details you have to import :

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
```

in your jsp page .